# Java Swing, Changing text value from Booleans

Tags: java, swing, boolean, textfield

So, I'm just experimenting with GUI, and I wish to change the text value once a Button has been pressed.

Here's some code below: ( Note, Acceleration is a Private Boolean declared within the class)

```
JButton btnAcceleration = new JButton("Acceleration");
    btnAcceleration.setBounds(10, 142, 121, 23);
    btnAcceleration.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Acceleration = true;

        }
    });
```

This is the button, that makes the Boolean true (Once clicked)

```
JTextField ValueA = new JTextField();
    ValueA.setText("Value A");
    ValueA.setBounds(490, 141, 66, 22);
    contentPane.add(ValueA);
    ValueA.setEditable(false);
    ValueA.setVisible(false);

    if (Acceleration) {
        ValueA.setText("Force");
        ValueA.setVisible(true);
    }
```

And here's the desired code I wish to run. When I test the GUI I don't get any errors in the console, however, this code does not work, the Text Field does not appear, and even with it visible, the text doesn't change? Anyone know how to fix this? (I have also tried enabling TextEditiable, same result)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is one of magical thinking. You're creating the ValueA field on GUI creation, and you have code to make it visible if a boolean is true, but this code is only called once on GUI creation and will not magically be re-called when the boolean is changed. To solve this problem, simply move that code

```
ValueA.setText("Force");
ValueA.setVisible(true);
```

to the ActionListener code, so that it is called when the listener is invoked.

Note that when changing the visibility of a component as you're doing, you'll want to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on its container so that it is accurately displayed.

As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Ah, thanks a bunch , been learning Java over the past few months, just decided to take a little dive into GUI, thanks for the feedback